# How to extend the size of image frame in Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a simple project using OpenCV and Python. I am reading a video frame by frame to show in window which looks like this:

[image: Original frame which I have right now]

Now, I want to extend the size (height) of frame to add some extra space, which can be used to add extra information. After adding extra space in frame, it should look like this:

[image: Image frame after adding extra space at bottom (I did this in MS Paint)]

How can I add extra space in frame by giving extra height/size?

Comment: Read [OpenCV2.0](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html) or [OpenCV3.0](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) That might give you a good start. In the end, however, there is a limit to how much OpenCv can do with Qt (and it can only do Qt). The way forward is probably embedding the video in a Tk or Qt app and then running OpenCv in the background and just retrieving the numerical results over it and displaying them again through Tk or Qt, thus ignoring the OpenCV ability to display videos etc...

Comment: you can do it by using [cv2.copyMakeBorder()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.12/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html?highlight=copymakeborder)

Comment: create a new image of your wanted size and copy your old image to a subimage of the new image.

Comment: @sturkmen Thank you so much for your idea. By adding only bottom border, I exactly got what i wanted to do. I have added a line in my code: cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame,0,60,0,0,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[35, 177, 77])

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the thing:

```
import numpy as np

def extend_image_height(image: np.ndarray, height: int, color):
    image_extended = np.ndarray((image.shape[0] + height,) + image.shape[1:], dtype=image.dtype)
    image_extended[:image.shape[0], :] = image
    image_extended[image.shape[0]:, :] = color
    return image_extended
```

`image` is the image that you need to extend, `height` is the height of the extra space, `color` is the color to fill the extra space.